# Generating Date Range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, timestamp

I have a Google Sheet that contains extracted metadata from a large amount of files that I transferred from CDs to a server.  I am currently working on creating a description for these materials to include in a finding aid.  I found it easiest to work in Excel or Sheets because the PUI we use to output our finding aids utilizes a spreadsheet upload plugin.

I've been using pivot tables in Google Sheets to sort through all of the data with little issue except when I need to generate a date range for the files contained in one CD.  Essentially, I'm creating a pivot table that contains rows for the URI, Filename (in this case I'm filtering for folder name only), and date_modified.  The data looks something like this:

| URI | FILENAME | DATE_MODIFIED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| URI1 | FOLDER1 | 2000-01-01 |
| URI1 | FOLDER2 | 2000-01-01 |
| URI1 | FOLDER3 | 2000-02-01 |
| URI1 | FOLDER4 | 1999-12-02 |
| URI2 | FOLDER1 | 2001-01-20 |

... and so on.

I'd like to generate a date range for each unique URI.  I realize I could just go through each unique URI and manually extract that data but I have a LOT of these to go through so I don't think it is the most efficient use of my time.  Especially, when you notice that the dates do not follow a chronological order. I'm thinking that pivot tables are not going to help me here so if anyone has other suggestions I'm happy to listen but brownie points if anyone has a solution that works in Sheets!

Comment: by "date range" do you mean two dates? like the first and last?

Comment: Yes, but it needs to be the earliest date to the latest date.  So, in the example above, the date range would need to look like this--> 1999-12-02-2000-02-01 for URI1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on a new tab somewhere.

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:C,"select A,MIN(C),MAX(C) where A<>'' group by A")
```

change the range ref to suit.

Then in the next column over, depending on where you output the query,

```
=IF(A2="",,TEXT(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"-"&TEXT(C2,"yyyy-mm-dd"))
```

drag down to the bottom.

Comment: That sort of worked.  The only issue is that when I do this: =QUERY(Sheet1!A:C,"select A,MIN(C),MAX(C) where A<>'URI' group by A") I'd rather be able to add the cell ID rather than have to type out the URI every time.  So, like this: =QUERY(Sheet1!A:C,"select A,MIN(C),MAX(C) where A<>'A2' group by A"). Does that make sense?

Comment: Edit: am I supposed to put the URI between the quote marks after A<>''? If I don't put anything there then it doesn't work.  I end up with the same date which happens to be the first date on the list. But when I add the URI, it pulls the correct dates but removes the URI from A2 which causes the second part not to work.

Comment: This works.  I was using it against a previous pivot table which it did not like.  Using it against the original data works beautifully! Thanks!

Comment: @BatonRougeRoom glad to hear it!  Can you leave a comment here with what the final formula looked like in case it might help others in the future?

Comment: I used exactly what you posted above.  The issue I had originally was that I was using the formula on a pivot table which it didn't like and also, I was adding the cell ID (A2) when it didn't need to.  The formula works great and has saved me quite a bit of time!